# Expansion of a function with square root

Tags: calculus

> Expand $\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-2x}}$ as a series in ascending powers of $x$, up to and including the term in $x^2$. State the range of values of $x$ for which the expansion is valid. Use the first three non-zero terms of the series to estimate $\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$, giving your answer as a fraction in its lowest term.

I am having trouble attempting the expansion of the above function with the square root and fraction complicating the derivatives.. Also, with the square root, how will there be an $x^2$ term?

Comment: One idea is taylor expand the numerator and denominator separately, then multiply terms and collect the ones up to and including $x^2$

Comment: $$1+\frac{3 x}{2}+\frac{15 x^2}{8}+O\left(x^3\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-2x}}
&=(1+x)^{1/2}(1-2x)^{-1/2}\\
&=(1+\frac12 x+\frac12(-\frac12)\frac{x^2}{2}+...)
(1+(-\frac12)(-2x)+(-\frac12)(-\frac32)\frac{(-2x)^2}{2}+...)\\
&=(1+\frac12 x-\frac18x^2+...)
(1+x+\frac32 x^2+...)\\
&=1 + \frac32 x
+(\frac32+\frac12-\frac18) x^2+...\\
&=1 + \frac32 x
+\frac{15}{8} x^2+...\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

$$1+\frac{3 x}{2}+\frac{15 x^2}{8}+O\left(x^3\right)$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apply $\frac1{1-t}=1+t+t^2$ and $\sqrt{1+t}= 1+\frac12 -\frac18t^2$ in the expansion below

$$\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-2x}}= \sqrt{\frac32\frac{1}{1-2x}-\frac12}
= \sqrt{\frac32(1+2x+4x^2)-\frac12}\\
= \sqrt{1+3x+6x^2}= 1+\frac32 x+\frac{15}8x^2
$$

Then, let $x=\frac18$ to approximate

$$\sqrt{\frac32} \approx 1+\frac32 \cdot \frac18 +\frac{15}8\cdot \frac1{8^2}=1.217$$

Alternatively,

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-2x}}$ and calculate

$$f’(x)= \frac3{2(1-2x)^{3/2}(1+x)^{1/2}}, \>\>\>\>\>f’’(x)= \frac{3(8x+5)}{4(1-2x)^{5/2}(1+x)^{3/2}}$$

Then,

$$f(x)=f(0)+f’(0)x+\frac12f’’(0)x^2= 1+\frac32x +\frac{15}8x^2$$